# URL key for specified store already exists in Magento 2.1.1

Tags: category, magento-2.1, url-rewrite

I am trying to Update Category name in Magento 2.1.1 but its throwing "URL key for specified store already exists.".

This error is appearing in some categories while other categories are working fine.

```
main.CRITICAL: exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException' with message 'URL key for specified store already exists.' in D:\xampp\htdocs\m2demo\vendor\magento\module-url-rewrite\Model\Storage\AbstractStorage.php:85
```

I am just upadating category name.

Let me know if any one can help me.

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: it means already same category exist in store. check category first.

Comment: I am unable to find the same category in magento admin. Is there any other place where i can check?

Comment: You can search it directly in database.

Comment: Can you please tell me in which database table?

Comment: You can find it in 'catalog_category_entity_varchar' table.

Comment: @SanjayJethva Did you solve this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue in more than 3-4 projects.

If you want to resolve this issue, you can upgrade your version with latest one or try below code logic:

Try this solution by overriding below function in your custom module :)

Path: vendor/magento/module-url-rewrite/Model/Storage

```
protected function doReplace(array $urls){ 
    $this->deleteOldUrls($urls); 
    $data = [];
    $storeId_requestPaths = [];
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $storeId = $url->getStoreId();
        $requestPath = $url->getRequestPath();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM url_rewrite where store_id = $storeId and request_path = '$requestPath'";
        $exists = $this->connection->fetchOne($sql); 
        if ($exists) continue;
        $storeId_requestPaths[] = $storeId . '-' . $requestPath;
        $data[] = $url->toArray();
    }

    // Remove duplication data;
    $n = count($storeId_requestPaths);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n - 1; $i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $n; $j++) {
            if ($storeId_requestPaths[$i] == $storeId_requestPaths[$j]) {
                unset($data[$j]);
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        $this->insertMultiple($data);
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException $e) {
        /** @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite[] $urlConflicted */
        $urlConflicted = [];
        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            $urlFound = $this->doFindOneByData(
                [
                    UrlRewriteData::REQUEST_PATH => $url->getRequestPath(),
                    UrlRewriteData::STORE_ID => $url->getStoreId(),
                ]
            );
            if (isset($urlFound[UrlRewriteData::URL_REWRITE_ID])) {
                $urlConflicted[$urlFound[UrlRewriteData::URL_REWRITE_ID]] = $url->toArray();
            }
        }
        if ($urlConflicted) {
            throw new \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\Exception\UrlAlreadyExistsException(
                __('URL key for specified store already exists.'),
                $e,
                $e->getCode(),
                $urlConflicted
            );
        } else {
            throw $e->getPrevious() ?: $e;
        }
    }

    return $urls;
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Thanks,

Ketan T.